# closed subspace of $\ell_1$ such that sequences of alternating terms cover $\ell_1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

If $X$ is a closed subspace of $\ell_1$ such that every sequence $y=(x_{2n})\in\ell_1$ can be seen as the 'every other term' sequence given by some $x=(x_n)\in X$, why must there be a constant $C$ such that for any $y$ this $x$ can be chosen to satisfy $|x|\leq C|y|$?

Maybe there's a nice explicit formula for the choice of $x$ (so we don't have to use the Axiom of Choice?) We might be able to define a linear operator $y\mapsto x$ and prove that it must be continuous and therefore bounded.

Or maybe we have to resort to an existence proof? I've tried rewriting the problem in terms of suprema so as to be able to use the Uniform Boundedness Principle, but got an infimum coming in. I suspect we need to use *completeness* of $X$ rather than using closedness directly, but can't really see how to use either.

Many thanks for any help with this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's phrase your problem like this: let $T : X \to \ell^1$ be the "every other term" operator, i.e. $(Tx)_n = x_{2n}$.  Clearly $T$ is linear and bounded, and your hypothesis says that $T$ is surjective.  $X$ and $\ell^1$ are both complete, so the open mapping theorem applies to $T$...

I'll let you take it from here, but feel free to comment if you need another hint.